# MySQL error : Variable 'collation_connection' can't be set to the value of 'NULL' when dump .sql file

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I got error `Variable 'collation_connection' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'` when using sequelPro to dump .sql file.

Here is the beginning of my .sql file:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Here is the end of my .sql file:

```
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

I've run `mysql -u root -p -e "set global net_buffer_length=1000000; set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;"` according to answers on stackoverflow.But it's still not working.

Server version: 5.7.11 Homebrew

Answer (score 4):

The [COLLATION_CONNECTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_collation_connection) is a server variable. MySQL throws an error when NULL value is set to this variable. For example:

```
SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = null; -- error!
SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION; -- error, when @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION is NULL!
```

It is possible that sequelPro used different MySQL sessions (connections) to run the script.

- SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION - was run at one session
- SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION - was run at another session, where @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION had not been set.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This was exactly what was happening in my case as the database file was large and timed-out. Adding /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */; before /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */; at the end of my sql file fixed this error for me

Answer (score 2):

I was using sequelPro when I run this .sql file and then got this error.But I tried `mysql -u username -p databasename < filename.sql` and it worked!I have no idea of what's going on.But it worked.Hope this can help anyone who got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error info when using sequel pro, but using Navicat does not have the problem.